# Can't have my Navigation bottom bar in another activity

Tags: java, android

I want to understand how can I get the Navigation Bottom bar in another activity.

[image]

I tried this but it still not works:

MainActivity :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        mTextMessage = findViewById(R.id.message);
        navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    }

}
```

And here my other activity :

```
    private TextView mTextMessage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        mTextMessage = findViewById(R.id.message);
        navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener); // not working actually...
    }
}
```

My logs :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView$OnNavigationItemSelectedListener)
```

Comment: Hello sir, why you want to get navigation bottom from another activity?

Comment: Hi ! because I want to keep the navigation bar in another activity (I just edited the post to see in the capture)

Comment: you are not using fragment ?

Comment: use fragment inside of main activity that helps you to keep the navigation in all pages.